# Python Pandas if column id value greater

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

I have what i think is a simple quesiton, but I am not sure how to implement.
I have the following dataframe:

```
ID    Value
1     100
2     250
3     300
4     400
5     600
7     800
```

I would like to look at 2 id's: 3 & 5 and then drop the one with the lower value.  So i am assuming I would use something like the following code, but again, i am not sure how to implement,nor am i sure how to utilize the inequality to point towards the value while directing my function at a very specific pair of id's.

```
def ChooseGreater(x):
    if df['id'] == 3 > df['id'] ==5
        return del df['id']==5
    else:
        return del df['id']==3
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can do:

```
df.drop(df.loc[df.ID.isin([3,5]),'Value'].idxmin(), inplace=True)
```

Comment: sacul, thank you very much!  incredibly easy and efficient!

Answer (score 3):

#### Using Python's `min`

```
df.drop(min(df.query('ID in [3, 5]').index, key=df.Value.get))

   ID  Value
0   1    100
1   2    250
3   4    400
4   5    600
5   7    800
```

---

#### `groupby` and `tail`

```
df.sort_values('Value').groupby(df.ID.replace({3: 5})).tail(1)

   ID  Value
0   1    100
1   2    250
3   4    400
4   5    600
5   7    800
```

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate `idxmin` and then use `np.in1d` with `pd.DataFrame.loc`:

```
idx = df.loc[df['ID'].isin([3,5]), 'Value'].idxmin()
res = df.loc[~np.in1d(df.index, idx)]

print(res)

   ID  Value
0   1    100
1   2    250
3   4    400
4   5    600
5   7    800
```

Answer (score 1):

This is method from `groupby`

```
df.loc[df.Value.groupby((~df.ID.isin([3,5])).sort_values().cumsum()).idxmax()].sort_index()
Out[167]: 
   ID  Value
0   1    100
1   2    250
3   4    400
4   5    600
5   7    800
```